# What are we doing on this site?

Tags: discussion

I described this site to a friend as "the best place I know to spend time constructively when you should be working".  But it occurred to me that I don't know the exact way to describe what we're doing.  Mark Twain said "work is whatever a body is obliged to do, and play is whatever a body is not obliged to do", but we're not exactly playing.  On the other hand, I wouldn't (unless desperate for something to put on my CV), call it voluntary work.  Is there a word or short phrase for what you're doing at this moment?

Comment: Learning :) -- For each tidbit I contribute, I receive a wealth of information about a topic I'm interested in.

Comment: "I don't know how to waste my time better than to do it here."

Comment: We are fixing the world, one grammar mistake at a time.

Answer (score 7):

Me personally, I'm edifying.  And excogitating.  Not necessarily in that order.

Comment: Based on some criteria I couldn't begin to figure out, EL&U 'site management tools' auto-classify your answer as 'potentially low quality'. Personally I'd say it's fine, but could be improved by adding *exploring*, for example (assuming you want to stick with e's, *and* that this applies in your case). What the hell - it's good enough for an upvote even as it stands, just for the word *excogitating*. Much better than plain old *cogitating*, for thinking not just 'out loud', but 'out there on the net'.

Comment: Really? Low quality?  I must not have enough words. `I have words, too many words, and no speech.`

Comment: @Kit: Nah - prolly summat to do with some very simple rules being followed by a routine that decides your wording is potentially ungrammatical. And let's be honest, you shouldn't really start sentences with **And**. Not to mention **Not**.

Comment: You'll have to add *encountering* if we keep meeting like this :-)

Comment: I prefer *liaising*. I'm sure the period-to-word ratio has somfing to do wid it as well.

Comment: I bet you're right there. Anyway, a few 'false positives' doesn't mean it's not a useful tool. And EL&U *is* a good site for liaising and coming to a consensus, I find. Language would be in trouble if we could only establish 'proper' current usage by consulting authoritative books which invariably lag some way behind the times.

Comment: So the auto-classification must be one of those arcane "moderator tools", huh? I've got a ways to go before I get there. Is `concensus` a British spelling?  I like this site too, but there's nothing wrong with a good etymological tome or two.  They make good brain-eats.

Comment: Duh. Concensus was me still in mind of the fact that earlier today I was pontificating about the recent 10-year UK Census. I don't know how many points you need to activate the *'Review'* button, but my guess is you'll be there pretty soon.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIC, this question was perfectly positioned in English.stackexchange. It is not a discussion about the "behaviour" on the site, but a question about a word that can be used to describe the activity of the participants of the site. Hence, it is a question about language use and vocabulary.

I feel it should be moved back.

Comment: Are you saying it’s not an appropriate question for the meta site?

Comment: 1: _Your_ answer is definitely appropriate for meta, 2: There are many kinds of meta: talking about the operation of the ELU site, talking about language in general, talking 'about' things rather talking of them. 3: Rereading the question, there is nothing ELU specific in it...could almost be in meta.SO. That said, it wasn't too weird in main.ELU (maybe a little of topic), but now that it's here no reason to move.

Comment: Well, after the introduction sentences, the actual question is "Is there a word or short phrase for what you're doing at this moment?" And that is a question about English. If you all agree that the thread should stay in Meta, that's fine. But I feel it had its place in the English site.

Comment: If I had a vote, it would be in English.  Which is why I posted it there.

Comment: I take the point that the question itself is about the English language. However, I think the "meta-ness" that the question is also about the site means the question should be on meta. A reworded question about a hypothetical site similar to this one probably would be fine to stay on the main site.

Comment: @Tim,@teylyn: oh. I missed that part, about 'a word or short phrase. bad reading attention.

Comment: @teylyn: *Technically speaking*, I agree completely with your point. But let's be honest - I'm sure even OP knows perfectly well that this question is bound to generate much more discussion about the *exact nature* of the activity than about what to actually call it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say I'm "participating" in a direct sense, and "exploring" in a general one. I do agree with Twain, though: "play" is anything you don't have to do. Which only means you have to play like you work -- as profitably as you can -- and that too takes experimenting, practice and risk.

Answer (score 1):

The main candidates for me are **contributing** and **participating**.

If I have to pick just one, it'll be the former. You could *participate* in Second Life, for example, without really implying you do anything to improve that site.